# Update table based on GROUP BY and SUM "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'." Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my table and present the table where it is showing the listed columns as well as the new `Sum_Value` column and creating this based on grouping the listed names Name, Line, Type, but I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

at the `select` statement when running the code

This is my code:

```
update #testTempTbl4
select Name, Line, Type,
SUM(Value) as Sum_Value
from #testTempTbl4
group by Name, Line, Type;
```

Using SSMS

Comment: [Check the official MS docs for `UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - it's **always** `UPDATE (table) SET (column) = (value), (column) = (value) .....`

Comment: Are any of those grouping columns nullable?

Comment: okay would it be easier to do a insert into statment

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do... are you trying to update an existing table or insert into a new table? You can do either, but you need to use the correct syntax which is well documented.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: @DaleK i was trying to do it to the existing table but into a new table would be good too, really either or just wasnt sure if i was using the select statement correctly

Comment: Check the documentation (you're not lol)

Comment: Please provide a [mre], even for what you think are simple questions; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: And as has been mentioned on your previous question SSMS is purely a client UI... instead post the results of `select @@version`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish what you want by using a *windowed* `SUM()` function in a *subquery* to calculate the sum and then setting the value in the outer `UPDATE` statement.

Something like

```
UPDATE T
SET Sum_Value = Calulated_Sum_Value
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Line, Type) AS Calulated_Sum_Value
    FROM #testTempTbl4
) T;
```

A subselect is needed here because you can't use a window function directly in the `UPDATE` statement. The `OVER()` qualified defined the scope of the `SUM()` calculation.

The subselect can also be placed in a *Common Table Expression* (CTE) as follows:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Line, Type) AS Calulated_Sum_Value
    FROM #testTempTbl4
)
UPDATE T
SET Sum_Value = Calulated_Sum_Value;
```

(Credit Dale K for the CTE suggestion.)

Another option is to join your table with a subquery that contains the equivalent of your original logic.

```
UPDATE T
SET Sum_Value = S.Calulated_Sum_Value
FROM #testTempTbl4 T
JOIN (
    SELECT
        Name, Line, Type,
        SUM(Value) AS Calulated_Sum_Value
    FROM #testTempTbl4
    GROUP BY Name, Line, Type
) S
   ON S.Name = T.Name
   AND S.Line = T.Line
   AND S.Type = T.Type;
```

The results are the same for all three of the above.

You might even be able to incorporate the *windowed `SUM()`* calculation back into the code that initially populates `#testTempTbl4`.

Sample results:

| Name | Line | Type | Value | Sum_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 11 | 66 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 22 | 66 |
| A | 1 | 1 | 33 | 66 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 444 | 999 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 555 | 999 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0l_GJhrt) for a demo.

Comment: An updatable CTE would probably also do the job.

Comment: @DaleK - Good suggestion - perhaps a bit cleaner. I added the CTE variant to the answer.